# Why aren't the Tailwind classes taking effect in my Vite React project?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, vite

I have a Vite React project that uses Tailwind via PostCSS. However, none of the classes are reflecting the the localhost. Below are the files in the project:

**postcss.config.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
    }
}
```

**tailwind.config.js:**

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

**App.js:**

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
        Hello world!
      </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

This was all done following the instructions in the Tailwind documentation at https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The problem is likely your filenames. They contain JSX so they should have the `.jsx` file extension (a new Vite + React scaffolded project would warn about this). Also, the Tailwind `content` config should include `.jsx`. See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vite-react-tailwind).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should update the `tailwind.config.js` file to include .jsx files:

`{html,js} => {html,js,jsx}`

```js
module.exports = {
  content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,jsx}"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the error can be Unknown at rule @tailwindcss

To solve this you must download this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=csstools.postcss)